# What notation should I use for indexed family?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

So I've just started learning a bit of topology and set theory and im getting confused on definitions of indexed family.

I've seen various websites and books describe an indexed family of sets like this

$\{A_{i}|i\in I \}$ is a function $S:I\longrightarrow A$ and we write $A_{i}$ instead of $S(i)$.

But on a post I saw on here I understood that an indexed family can contain repeated elements if this is so why do we use set builder notation to describe a family?
Shouldn't it be something more like $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ in this case the braces do not indicate a set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ usually is a sequence, like $(U_1,U_2,U_3,\ldots, )$

Comment: A "family" of sets is a set of sets. To "index" it can be (in some cases) an helpful way to describe it. Silly example: $A_i = \{ i \}, i \in \mathbb N$. It is the "family": $\{ \{  1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \ldots \}$

Comment: No, a family of sets is *not* a set of sets. A family $I\ni i\mapsto A_i$ is not determined only by its image $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, both notations you describe are in use.  Some people use $\{A_{i}\mid i\in I \}$ (or interchangeably, $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$) to denote an indexed family, and others use $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ or $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ (there are also other variations you will occasionally see, like $\langle A_i\rangle_{i\in I}$).  Personally, I strongly agree with you that the first notation doesn't make sense for an indexed family, since it should be describing a set, not a function.  So I would say that $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ denotes the indexed family itself whereas $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ denotes the *set* of terms of the indexed family, i.e. the *image* of the function $I\to A$.  However, this convention is not universal and some authors use $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ for the indexed family itself, or simply do not make a clear distinction between the indexed family and its image.

Answer (score 0):

I think a concise way to put it is that an indexed family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is the set $\{ (i, A_i) \,|\, i\in I \}$

which of course differs from the set $\{ A_i \,|\, i\in I \}$
and in precisely the desirable way.

For example:  $(A_i)_{i\in I} = (B_i)_{i\in I} \iff \forall i\in
I \; A_i = B_i $ which is what you expect from a ... respectable family. For family equality it is not enough, as with equality of sets, to include identical members. Members have to be identical for every single value of the index.

The set of pairs above is an alternative way to express the index mapping, of course, but more economical as you don't have to bother giving the mapping a name which you never intend to use. Which, by the way, is the very reason why indexed families are used instead of explicitly specifying the index mapping.