# Why are families of sets sometimes denoted with $(-)$ instead of $\{ - \}$?

Tags: notation, set-theory

Why are set families sometimes denoted with $(-)$ instead of $\{ - \}$?

In particular, I often see open covers of a topological space being notated as $(U_i)_{i \in I}$, or an arbitrary family of indexed sets notated as $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$, for example.

I have always wondered, why the use of parenthesis instead of curly brackets?

**Edit:** For an example, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.03571), page 7. (this is just the most recent one, though I can't think of any other papers off-hand that use this notation, but I've definitely seen it a lot).

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer, because I genuinely don't know what the answer is.  However, the notation $(U_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is pretty standard notation for a sequence of sets (which can be thought of as an *ordered* family of sets).  I would imagine that the contexts in which you are seeing this notation are contexts in which the family of sets is playing an analogous role to a *sequence* of sets (though, perhaps, with an uncountable or unordered index set).

Comment: OK, yeah, using that for a sequence of sets makes sense. Perhaps that notation just got unconsciously carried over into settings where the indexing sets aren't ordered (e.g. a cover of a topological space has no "natural" ordering), and it just stuck around.

Comment: Why are families (of sets or whatsoever) sometimes denoted with $\{ - \}$ instead of $(- )?$ Yet families are not sets!

Comment: I only meant I view a family $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ not as a set (set of what?) but as a map $\lambda\mapsto A_\lambda.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I see. That makes sense. I was initially confused because as long as $\Lambda$ is a set, then one could view $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ as a set of sets. That seems implicit in $\Lambda$ being an indexing "set" though I guess it could be a proper class.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus: The point is that $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is *not* the same thing as $\{A_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$.  The first denotes the *function* on $\Lambda$ which sends $\lambda$ to $A_\lambda$ and the second denotes the *image* of that function.  (Unfortunately, some people also use $\{A_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ to instead denote the function.)

Comment: A family is *not* a set of sets, at least not in the obvious naive interpretation $\{A_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}.$ E.g. a sequence is *not* the set of its values. Two distinct sequences can have the same image.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see. I was not aware of that notation for a function, but I can see the distinction now.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003278/what-notation-should-i-use-for-indexed-family